# how to make camera moves slower when moving along a curve

Tags: animation, camera, path

I've been looking for a solution for several hours but got no luck..

Is there a way to make the camera's footstep smaller when moving "follow path"? (camera moves along a curve)

Put it another way, how can I decrease the distance on the curve that the camera moves between two frames? (in python script)

By default it moves way too fast...

Comment: In python script? It is easy outside of a script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the curve selected;
Select the Object Data tab in the Properties window,
In the Path Animation panel change the Frames value, higher values result in a slower follow speed.
[image]

---

***Edit:***
This value can be modified in python using the following line;

```
bpy.data.curves["NurbsPath"].path_duration = X
```

where ***NurbsPath*** is the name of your curve, and ***X*** is the value you would like to set.

Comment: Yep, that is how you do it. The OP said something about doing it from a script though.

Comment: yes! bpy.data.curves["NurbsPath"].path_duration = X the X is exactly what the Frames in picture

Comment: I get an error message when I try to add a keyframe to the Evaluation Tine.